# npm start failure express

Tags: windows, node.js, express

I am using git bash on windows and have started a project using node.js and express and npm start fails at the json start script. Typing 'node ./bin/www/', however works. What can I do to fix this so npm start works?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "Failed at the app2@0.0.0 start script. Exit status -1.  no ok code 0

Comment: What's your `package.json`?

Comment: {
  "name": "app2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0"
  }
}